# Can't enter data in Content field when sending List Email

Tags: email

I have a user who cannot enter text into the Content field when trying to send a List Email.  He can select users to send to & can enter a subject line.  He doesn't see the icons at the top of the rich text field.  Below is an image of what he sees.  This works for other users.  I can login to his account & it works for me.  He has tried using Firefox and Chrome. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by checking browser setting & enabling JavaScript.